# Jquery is not working in php block

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<body>
<ul id="M8" class="Mh"><li ><a id="atagid" class="msub" href="javascript:;
"onclick="trackchange();" >Track Change(OFF)</a></li></ul>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['track'])){
echo "<script>alert('working');</script>";
echo "<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#atagid').css('color','green');
$('#atagid').html('Track Change(ON)');
});</script>";
}
?>
<script>
 function trackchange(){
 $('#atagid').css('color','green');$('#atagid').html('Track Change(ON)');}
//This function is working but in php block it is not working
</script>

</body>
```

If `$_SESSION['track']` is set then the html element `a` color  should be changed to green and the content should be changed to `Track change(ON)`.
 
 In this script `alert` function is working which confirms the session variable, but content and color of a tag is not getting changed. I couldn't to find where am I doing wrong.

Comment: Where are you putting your jquery file?

Comment: Your code doesnt tell where is the jQuery.

Comment: Coz i ran your code in my local and it was working fine. The probable issue with your code is misplacement of jQuery file.

Comment: jquery was in body section. I replaced it to head now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable issue with your code is misplacement of jQuery file, Just try to put it in the `<head>...</head>`.

Comment: As you just saw, It raised an error. But if you would be doing this with AJAX it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery first by using

```
<script src="point/to/your/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: He already has jQuery because `trackchange()` function is working.